# If we know that a positive integer x can be represented as sum of squares of two numbers, what can we say about neighbours of x?

Tags: number-theory

Let $x, p, q, i$ all be positive integers.

If we know that,

$x = p^2 + q^2$

Then is there a way to find out that, can $x+i$ be also represented as sum of squares of two positive numbers without checking for all combinations of two positive numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fundamental result on this matter is

> Let $n$ be a natural number and let $n=k^2\cdot m$, where $m$ is
>   square free, i.e. in the decomposition of $m$ to a product of primes,
>   there is no prime in with power greater or equal to 2. $n$ is sum of
>   two squares if and only if $m$ does not consist any prime factor of
>   the form $4t+3$.

Moreover, this result gives us slightly better identification of such numbers,

> A natural number $n$ is sum of two squares,if and only if in the
>   decomposition of $n$ to prime factors, every factor of the form $4t+3$
>   appears with even power.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is "no". Whether or not a number can be represented as the sum of two squares depends (in a mildly complicated way) on how the number factors as a product of primes. Knowing how $n$ factors isn't much help when you want to know how nearby numbers factor.

It is known (and not hard to prove) that numbers congruent to 3 modulo 4 can't be the sum of two squares. There are always some of those nearby.